# How to print page in plain text format for matrix-dot printer?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

I know that there have been so many questions similar to this in SO and I have tried most of the solutions but I still am not getting the result that I want, I am using an epson LX300+II printer and I want to print my page from my web based application in a plain format (as how the print result should be when printing from a notepad). When I tried printing straight away using google chrome, I think the printer perceived the text and tables as a picture, rather that the plain letter therefore the print result is not good as expected print result looked zoomed, font looked stretch, padding are too wide and so on.

I want the printer to read the letters and text as letters in its own default font. I am using mostyle PHP, javascript, html, css. How can I possibly achieve this ? Or if there's any other language that could achieve this, please do recommend me.

All solutions and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here are several options for achieving this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783269/3196753

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who need to print using dot-matrix printer from a browser, use QZ Tray (https://qz.io/)